# How to validate a 12 digit phone Number using javascript and bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to validate a 12 digit phone number in the form of this format
92xxxxxxxxxx.

eg:923337690977, 921234567890

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
            // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                first_name: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your first name'
                        }
                    }
                },
                last_name: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your last name'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your email address'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                phone: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your phone number'
                        },
                        phone: {
                            country: 'PK',
                            message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
                        }
                    }
                },
                address: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 8,
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your street address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                city: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 4,
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your city'
                        }
                    }
                },
                state: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please select your state'
                        }
                    }
                },
                zip: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your zip code'
                        },
                        zipCode: {
                            country: 'US',
                            message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
                        }
                    }
                },
                comment: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 10,
                            max: 200,
                            message: 'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
            $('#success_message').slideDown({
                    opacity: "show"
                }, "slow") // Do something ...
            $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        });
});
```

```css
    #success_message{ display: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap 3 Contact form with Validation</title>
  


  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>

      

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post"  id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Contact Us Today!</legend>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input name="phone" placeholder="923xxxxxxxx0" class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input name="city" placeholder="city" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Select Basic -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                        <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" >
                            <option value=" " >Please select your state</option>
                            <option>Alabama</option>
                            <option>Alaska</option>
                            <option >Arizona</option>
                            <option >Arkansas</option>
                            <option >California</option>
                            <option >Colorado</option>
                            <option >Connecticut</option>
                            <option >Delaware</option>
                            <option >District of Columbia</option>
                            <option> Florida</option>
                            <option >Georgia</option>
                            <option >Hawaii</option>
                            <option >daho</option>
                            <option >Illinois</option>
                            <option >Indiana</option>
                            <option >Iowa</option>
                            <option> Kansas</option>
                            <option >Kentucky</option>
                            <option >Louisiana</option>
                            <option>Maine</option>
                            <option >Maryland</option>
                            <option> Mass</option>
                            <option >Michigan</option>
                            <option >Minnesota</option>
                            <option>Mississippi</option>
                            <option>Missouri</option>
                            <option>Montana</option>
                            <option>Nebraska</option>
                            <option>Nevada</option>
                            <option>New Hampshire</option>
                            <option>New Jersey</option>
                            <option>New Mexico</option>
                            <option>New York</option>
                            <option>North Carolina</option>
                            <option>North Dakota</option>
                            <option>Ohio</option>
                            <option>Oklahoma</option>
                            <option>Oregon</option>
                            <option>Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option>Rhode Island</option>
                            <option>South Carolina</option>
                            <option>South Dakota</option>
                            <option>Tennessee</option>
                            <option>Texas</option>
                            <option> Uttah</option>
                            <option>Vermont</option>
                            <option>Virginia</option>
                            <option >Washington</option>
                            <option >West Virginia</option>
                            <option>Wisconsin</option>
                            <option >Wyoming</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control"  type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Website or domain name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
                        <input name="website" placeholder="Website or domain name" class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- radio checks -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Do you have hosting?</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="yes" /> Yes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="no" /> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text area -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Success message -->
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

    

</body>
</html>
```

The code is working fine for 10 digit phone number .but i need it for 12 digit phone number.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He're what you probably want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
      // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        first_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your first name'
            }
          }
        },
        last_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your last name'
            }
          }
        },
        email: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your email address'
            },
            emailAddress: {
              message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
            }
          }
        },
        phone: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your phone number'
            },
            // "regexp" instead of "phone"
            regexp: {
              regexp: /^92\d{10}$/,
              message: 'Please supply a valid phone number in the form 92xxxxxxxxxx'
            }
          }
        },
        address: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 8,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your street address'
            }
          }
        },
        city: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 4,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your city'
            }
          }
        },
        state: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please select your state'
            }
          }
        },
        zip: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your zip code'
            },
            zipCode: {
              country: 'US',
              message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
            }
          }
        },
        comment: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 10,
              max: 200,
              message: 'Please enter at least 10 characters and no more than 200'
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply a description of your project'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
      $('#success_message').slideDown({
          opacity: "show"
        }, "slow") // Do something ...
      $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

      // Prevent form submission
      e.preventDefault();

      // Get the form instance
      var $form = $(e.target);

      // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
      var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }, 'json');
    });
});
```

```css
#success_message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>
<div class="container">
  <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>
      <!-- Form Name -->
      <legend>Contact Us Today!</legend>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
            <input name="phone" placeholder="923xxxxxxxx0" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            <input name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            <input name="city" placeholder="city" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Select Basic -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
            <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker">
              <option value=" ">Please select your state</option>
              <option>Alabama</option>
              <option>Alaska</option>
              <option>Arizona</option>
              <option>Arkansas</option>
              <option>California</option>
              <option>Colorado</option>
              <option>Connecticut</option>
              <option>Delaware</option>
              <option>District of Columbia</option>
              <option>Florida</option>
              <option>Georgia</option>
              <option>Hawaii</option>
              <option>daho</option>
              <option>Illinois</option>
              <option>Indiana</option>
              <option>Iowa</option>
              <option>Kansas</option>
              <option>Kentucky</option>
              <option>Louisiana</option>
              <option>Maine</option>
              <option>Maryland</option>
              <option>Mass</option>
              <option>Michigan</option>
              <option>Minnesota</option>
              <option>Mississippi</option>
              <option>Missouri</option>
              <option>Montana</option>
              <option>Nebraska</option>
              <option>Nevada</option>
              <option>New Hampshire</option>
              <option>New Jersey</option>
              <option>New Mexico</option>
              <option>New York</option>
              <option>North Carolina</option>
              <option>North Dakota</option>
              <option>Ohio</option>
              <option>Oklahoma</option>
              <option>Oregon</option>
              <option>Pennsylvania</option>
              <option>Rhode Island</option>
              <option>South Carolina</option>
              <option>South Dakota</option>
              <option>Tennessee</option>
              <option>Texas</option>
              <option>Uttah</option>
              <option>Vermont</option>
              <option>Virginia</option>
              <option>Washington</option>
              <option>West Virginia</option>
              <option>Wisconsin</option>
              <option>Wyoming</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Website or domain name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
            <input name="website" placeholder="Website or domain name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- radio checks -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Do you have hosting?</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="yes" />Yes
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="no" />No
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Text area -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Success message -->
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>
      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="phone" placeholder="923xxxxxxxx0" value="" class="form-control" type="text">

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=phone]').val().startsWith('92'); // it returns boolean true: if match,false: if not match
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why would that do anything when you only execute it once when the page loads?